# How to join a Tables By Joining Columns? Means How To Add Join On Columns Name?

Tags: mysql

Suppose, I have two tables `hr_employee` and `hr_concept` with many different columns. Now um joining these two tables with join on tables.

```
SELECT hr_employee.name,
       hr_concept.name    
FROM hr_employee    
RIGHT JOIN hr_concept ON
      hr_employee.ad_client_id=hr_concept.ad_client_id
```

It returns the data by putting joins on tables. But I want to make a join on two columns.

Example: `name` column from `hr_employee` and `name` column from `hr_concept` and just join the columns by putting joins between column name and to specify a column name...not between the tables...?

Comment: Sorry, but your question is unclear.  To join on more than one column just use (for example) `... from hr_employee e join hr_concept c on e.ad_client=c.ad_client AND e.name=c.name`. If this isn't what you need you'll have to provide more details in your question.

Comment: I also don't get the question. Please explain more.

Comment: i want to make a join on column name between the tables by specify table name 'name' from hr_employee and 'name 'hr_concept..how to put a  join on these two column name

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for a JOIN similar to this:

```
SELECT hr_employee.name,
       hr_concept.name
FROM hr_employee
RIGHT JOIN hr_concept ON
      hr_employee.ad_client_id=hr_concept.ad_client_id AND
      hr_employee.name = hr_concept.name
```

If this is not the requirement, pl explain in detail.

Comment: if i add "AND hr_employee.name = hr_concept.name"...it returns full data from employee_name..and empty table from hr_concept.name....and if i write "ON hr_employee.ad_client_id=hr_concept.ad_client_id" it returns all the data from both tables..but my boss is saying that where is the join on name columns on tables?where u used join on columns??

Answer (score 0):

Use an alias for your tables and select that columns setting an alias too:

```
SELECT hre.name as employee_name,
       hrc.name as concept_name   
FROM hr_employee hre
RIGHT JOIN hr_concept hrc ON
      hre.ad_client_id=hrc.ad_client_id
```